# jQuery click/toggle reveal / hide div panels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I've trying to click reveal and hide some div's using jQuery. I've almost got it working, just a small bit i need help with.

Here's what i got so far: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rzw9fzz2/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#showmenu1').click(function() {
                $('.menu1').fadeToggle("fast");
                $('.menu2').hide();
                $('.menu3').hide();
                $('#showmenu2').hide();
                $('#showmenu3').hide();
                $(this).toggleClass('close');
        });
        $('#showmenu2').click(function() {
                $('.menu2').fadeToggle("fast");
                $('.menu1').hide();
                $('.menu3').hide();
                $('#showmenu1').hide();
                $('#showmenu3').hide();
                $(this).toggleClass('close');
        });
        $('#showmenu3').click(function() {
                $('.menu3').fadeToggle("fast");
                $('.menu1').hide();
                $('.menu2').hide();
                $('#showmenu1').hide();
                $('#showmenu2').hide();
                $(this).toggleClass('close');
        });
    });
```

It's working great, but if you click on any of the 'Link 1', 'Link 2' & 'Link 3' links it reveals the correct reveal div and hides the other 2 links (which is correct). What i then need it to do is if you then click the same Link panel the reveal hides, but i then also need the other 2 link panels to reappear. At the minute they stay hidden.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showmenu1').click(function() {
            $('.menu1').fadeToggle("fast");
            $('#showmenu2').toggle();
            $('#showmenu3').toggle();
            $(this).toggleClass('close');
    });
    $('#showmenu2').click(function() {
            $('.menu2').fadeToggle("fast");
            $('#showmenu1').toggle();
            $('#showmenu3').toggle();
            $(this).toggleClass('close');
    });
    $('#showmenu3').click(function() {
            $('.menu3').fadeToggle("fast");
            $('#showmenu1').toggle();
            $('#showmenu2').toggle();
            $(this).toggleClass('close');
    });
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/anoorally/rzw9fzz2/1/) :)

Use `toggle()` rather than `hide()` and you don't have to deal with other menus when they are not involved :)

Comment: Perfect thanks. Not sure why i didn't think of just using toggle instead of hide.

Comment: @UkatJalal [here is](http://jsfiddle.net/rzw9fzz2/4/) ur animation flavoured :) Could also use `fadeToggle()` for yet another flavor :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe toggle instead of hide the other ones:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showmenu1').click(function() {
            $('.menu1').fadeToggle("fast");
            $('.menu2').hide();
            $('.menu3').hide();
            $('#showmenu2').toggle();
            $('#showmenu3').toggle();
            $(this).toggleClass('close');
    });
    $('#showmenu2').click(function() {
            $('.menu2').fadeToggle("fast");
            $('.menu1').hide();
            $('.menu3').hide();
            $('#showmenu1').toggle();
            $('#showmenu3').toggle();
            $(this).toggleClass('close');
    });
    $('#showmenu3').click(function() {
            $('.menu3').fadeToggle("fast");
            $('.menu1').hide();
            $('.menu2').hide();
            $('#showmenu1').toggle();
            $('#showmenu2').toggle();
            $(this).toggleClass('close');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Check the updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rzw9fzz2/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showmenu1').click(function() {
        $('.menu1').fadeToggle("fast");
        $('.menu2').hide();
        $('.menu3').hide();
        $('#showmenu2').toggle();
        $('#showmenu3').toggle();
        $(this).toggleClass('close');
    });
    $('#showmenu2').click(function() {
        $('.menu2').fadeToggle("fast");
        $('.menu1').hide();
        $('.menu3').hide();
        $('#showmenu1').toggle();
        $('#showmenu3').toggle();
        $(this).toggleClass('close');
    });
    $('#showmenu3').click(function() {
        $('.menu3').fadeToggle("fast");
        $('.menu1').hide();
        $('.menu2').hide();
        $('#showmenu1').toggle();
        $('#showmenu2').toggle();
        $(this).toggleClass('close');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified a little bit your code. You may find it useful:

HTML:

```
<div id="showmenu1" class="panel">Link 1</div>
<div id="showmenu2" class="panel">Link 2</div>
<div id="showmenu3" class="panel">Link 3</div>

<div class="menu1">Link 1 reveal content</div> 
<div class="menu2">Link 2 reveal content</div>
<div class="menu3">Link 3 reveal content</div>
```

CSS:

```
.panel{width:150px;float:left;padding:50px;cursor:pointer;}
#showmenu1{background:#ffff00;}
#showmenu2{background:#ff0000;}
#showmenu3{background:#fAAA00;}
.menu1, .menu2, .menu3{float:left;background:#000;color:#fff;padding:50px; opacity: 0; display: none}

.hide-showmenu {
  display: none;
}

.display-menu {
  display: block;
}
.transition-menu {
  transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#showmenu1').click(function() {
            $('.menu1').toggleClass("display-menu");
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.menu1').toggleClass("transition-menu");
            });
            $("#showmenu2, #showmenu3, .menu2, .menu3").toggleClass("hide-showmenu");
            $(this).toggleClass('close');
    });
        $('#showmenu2').click(function() {
            $('.menu2').toggleClass("display-menu");
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.menu2').toggleClass("transition-menu");
            });
            $("#showmenu1, #showmenu3, .menu1, .menu3").toggleClass("hide-showmenu");
            $(this).toggleClass('close');
    });
        $('#showmenu3').click(function() {
            $('.menu3').toggleClass("display-menu");
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.menu3').toggleClass("transition-menu");
            });
            $("#showmenu1, #showmenu2, .menu1, .menu2").toggleClass("hide-showmenu");
            $(this).toggleClass('close');
    });
});
```

Fiddle Here: http://jsfiddle.net/rzw9fzz2/3/